# jQuery UI buttonset alignment

Tags: jquery-ui, radio-button

I'm trying to throw a list of radio buttons in a dialog for a user to select.  How do I make the lists that wrap align?  It would be nice to have them uniform or at least stretch out to the edge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Right now I just use `$("#mydiv").buttonset()`

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="ui-widget-header" style="padding-top: 5px">
    <input type="radio" name="slot" id="slot-1" value="1" /><label for="slot-1">7:10 AM - 7:50 AM</label>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You know the size of the dialog, so you can give all the buttons the same size to fill the space: `.ui-buttonset .ui-button { width: <your size> }`

Comment: @DidierG., this is what I ended up doing, please answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the width of your dialog, you could easily apply a width to the buttons elements for them to fill the space:

```
.ui-buttonset .ui-button { width: <your size> }
```